# Delay in pipeline component?

Tags: biztalk

In the solution we need to send a P.O. to three vendors however they need to in a sequence, e.g. always send to vendor 2 after send to vendor 1. Without introduce an orchestration, current solution is to add a manual delay in the pipeline component, e.g. sleep for one minute in the pipeline to vendor 2 and sleep for three minute to vendor 3.

Any better solution or do you see a flaw in this design? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **correct and only** reliable way to do this is with an **Orchestration**.  Such as scenario is exactly what they are for.

**There is absolutely nothing wrong with using an Orchestration.**  Meaning nothing.  There is no performance consideration, no maintenance consideration or anything else.

If someone is telling you not to use an Orchestration, tell us what their reasons are and we can help you explain to them how they are...mislead.

Answer (score 0):

The flaw in that design is if for some reason one of the send ports encounters an error and then goes into a retry state. e.g. Vendor 1 errors, message goes to message box to Retry in 5 min (default).  Vendor 2 gets sent after 1 minute delay, which is 4 minutes before Vendor 1.

I think your only reliable solution would be to use an Orchestration.